# Python : For Loop iterating through a csv list to scrape from CSV website

Tags: python, csv, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a loop that uses a column of names from a csv file in my path to pull data from a website that uses csv to hold its data. I need to iterate through each name and pass it to the website for a specific row  with five columns that is related to each name. I feel as though I have searched every thread pertaining to scraping a website that is holding data in a CSV file by using a CSV list.

I have tested the code that is in the for loop and it works independently to gather the specific row and columns based upon the name with one value in the parameter:

```
i  = 'City'
url = url_template.format(i)  # get the url
url = pd.read_csv(url)
url_df = pd.DataFrame(url)
my_data = url_df.iloc[[13]]
# my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_data) ## greyed out for testing

print my_data
```

However, when I attempt to run a loop:

```
import pandas as pd


url_template = "http://foo.html?t={}&spam=green&eggs=yellow"

# CSV file where retrieving column list
need_conv = (pd.read_csv('pract.csv')) # csv file

# column to use in the loop
need = need_conv['column']

# empty DataFrame
test_df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop to retrieve data and print

for i in need:  # for each year
    url = url_template.format(i)  # get the url
    url = pd.read_csv(url) # convert the data 
    url_df = pd.DataFrame(url) # create DataFrame from parsed data
    my_data = url_df.iloc[[13]] # upload specific row of data
    test_df =  test_df.append(my_data) # append data to empty dataframe

print test_df.head()
```

I receive an error:

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Help and feedback is very much appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without knowing the specific URLs. The first thing I would do would be to print `url` as the first thing in the loop to see which one is causing the error.

Comment: Check if the data is formatted and contains only printable characters. Also you can specify the encoding to read_csv

Comment: Thanks fuglede and Shijo. After  iterating back over the code like fuglede recommended, I found that the url was not concatenating properly because the .format()  was not correct in my code. The above code actually works perfectly. I hope it saves someone some of my headaches.